# How to discover sub types in mDNS

Tags: mdns

I am trying to discover based on subtypes. Ex: if i register a service using avahi-publish,

avahi-publish -s --domain="local" --subtype="_annon._sub._http._tcp" "ServiceName" "_http._tcp" 80 "TxtRecord=Some Text"

*I need to do service discover based on the subtype, "_annon._sub". Is there any way to do that?*

Answer (score 0):

You can query this with the linux command dig:

```
dig txt _annon._sub._http._tcp +short
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am fine with this.  But is it possible to register a service with avahi-publish and i need to send the sub-type as a response.  I am trying, but in the avahi-publish is not sending the subtype if i do service disvocer.